# Error:(1) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xml-parsing

On right clicking the error **"Error:(1) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)"** and then jump to source it opens the following activity_main.xml. I am not able to figure the error out

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    tools:context="com.example.utkarsh.beatle.app.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

**Andoridmanifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.utkarsh.beatle.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.utkarsh.beatle.app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ListView  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_view_forecast" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
tools:context="com.example.utkarsh.beatle.app.MainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>
```

**list_item_forecast.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire XML file? (use the edit button)

Comment: Post you full xml ..this is a well formed xml..you  may have onother error

Comment: The way you pasted your XML it seems as if you have white-space between < and FrameLayout. Please edit to make it look the same as your source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from **FrameLayout** to **RelativeLayout** in **activity_main.xml** solved the error, but I don't know how it worked and whats wrong in **FrameLayout**. But I got stuck to my previous problem , again I am getting no error messages but **My app doesn't show any ListView** when i run it on my device ,**blank white screen with app name written on top appears on clicking the app icon    in my device**. Others who are having the same problem  please help me and please check whether changing to **RelativeLayout** works or not.